# MySQL - How to insert value in all user's account

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

We have a CMS website where users can register and add money to their account. I don't want to bore you with the details, but the money the customers deposit is stored in their 'online wallet' and they can use this money to purchase products on our website.

I want to give every user $5.00.

I know how to manually insert $5.00 into a single user's record, but I don't know how I can do this for all users..

Here is the SQL code from a single record (I added $5 to user id 14013):

```
INSERT INTO  `database`.`databasetable` (
`iBalanceId` ,
`iUserId` ,
`eUserType` ,
`eBalType` ,
`fCreditAmount` ,
`fDebitAmount` ,
`dEntryDate` ,
`dValueDate` ,
`vDescritption` ,
`vBalTypeCode` ,
`iRefId` ,
`vRefTypeCode` ,
`iAddedUserId` ,
`eAddedUserType` ,
`vProcessDescription` ,
`eBalanceStatus`
)
VALUES (
'19499',  '14013',  'C',  'C',  '5.00',  '0.00',  '2016-02-04 21:11:54',  '2016-02-04',  'manual deposit',  'D',  '0',  'CR',  '0',  'S', 'manual deposit',  'A'
);
```

19499 is the record number

14013 is the user id that received the $5

How can I modify this SQL code to credit all users $5.00?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does the record number is auto increment?

Comment: use alter table records to set your column fCreditAmount = fCreditAmount + 5.00 like this without using any user id , Also add condition if you want.

Comment: Do you have a separate User table? How do you come up with record numbers?

Comment: @LearningMode - Did you mean `UPDATE` ?

Comment: Pretty sure you want to use an `INSERT ... SELECT FROM ...` statement, but it's impossible to help you write it without information about your users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have users already and just want to increase 5.00 for each users, so sql query will be.

```
UPDATE `database`.`databasetable` SET fCreditAmount = fCreditAmount + 5.00;
```

If you already increase one so you can except one.

```
UPDATE `database`.`databasetable` SET fCreditAmount = fCreditAmount + 5.00 WHERE iUserId != 14013 ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this.  However I forgot to mention one other thing.  eUserType needs to be 'C'.  For example we have several user types ('A', 'O', 'C', 'G', 'AF', 'N') and I need to credit all eUserType 'C'.

Comment: In where condition you can add this like _where eUserType = 'C'_.  Just dont provide userid to update for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Insert multi record to databasetable from user table.

I assume that iBalanceId is auto increment field!

```
INSERT INTO  `database`.`databasetable` (
`iUserId` ,
`eUserType` ,
`eBalType` ,
`fCreditAmount` ,
`fDebitAmount` ,
`dEntryDate` ,
`dValueDate` ,
`vDescritption` ,
`vBalTypeCode` ,
`iRefId` ,
`vRefTypeCode` ,
`iAddedUserId` ,
`eAddedUserType` ,
`vProcessDescription` ,
`eBalanceStatus`
)
(
    SELECT id as iUserId,
    'C' as eUserType,
    'C' as eBalType,
    '5.00' as fCreditAmount,  
    '0.00' as fDebitAmount,  
    '2016-02-04 21:11:54' as dEntryDate,  
    '2016-02-04' as dValueDate,  
    'manual deposit' as vDescritption,  
    'D' as vBalTypeCode,  
    '0' as iRefId,  
    'CR' as vRefTypeCode,  
    '0' as iAddedUserId,  
    'S' as  eAddedUserType, 
    'manual deposit' as vProcessDescription,  
    'A' as eBalanceStatus
    FROM user
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **already** have records in your table, then You need an UPDATE query for all rows:

```
UPDATE databasename SET fCreditAmount = fCreditAmount + 5.00 WHERE iUserId <> ''
```